# Time series with autoregressive error

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, econometrics, arima

How can I in R fit a time series, $x_t$, with external regressors, $v_t$, and an autoregressive error? This time series model is given as follows,
$x_t = \beta v_t + \epsilon_t$ where $\epsilon_t = w_t + \sum_{i = 1}^p \gamma_i\epsilon_{t - i}$ and $w_t \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `arima()` function in the stats package:

```
fit <- arima(x, xreg=v, order=c(p,0,0))
```

If you want the autoregressive order selected automatically, use `auto.arima()` from the forecast package:

```
fit <- auto.arima(x, xreg=v, seasonal=FALSE, max.q=0)
```

If you are willing to have more general correlated error structures:

```
fit <- auto.arima(x, xreg=v)
```

Comment: I used this package but I was under the assumption that `arima` will fit an autocorrelated time series of the form, $$x_t = \beta v_t + \sum_{i = 1}^p \gamma_i x_{t-i}} + \epsilon_t$$?

Comment: Read the help file.

Answer (score 1):

gls function in [nlme](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nlme/nlme.pdf) package can do it, with gls(y~x, data=Data.Frame, correlation=corARMA(p=1,q=0))