# Adjusting for the past using OLS regression with single lagged response

Tags: regression, time-series, least-squares, panel-data, endogeneity

There are many fine ways to handle a time series error structure in regression, for example as discussed in [Time Series with Autoregressive Error](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/119931/time-series-with-autoregressive-error). But consider a panel regression model of the form
$$
y_{it} = \alpha + \rho y_{it-1} + \beta x_{it} + \epsilon_{it},
$$ for subjects $i = 1, ..., N$ with $t$ as a single point in time (i.e., one current response and one lagged response are available for every subject $i$). Furthermore, suppose this model is fit with OLS regression, with the intuition being to estimate the impact of $x_{it}$ on $y_{it}$ "adjusted for the past."

Clearly if $\rho = 1$, we're modeling $\Delta y_{it}$, which seems fine for OLS regression (depending on the definition of $x_{it}$). So I'm thinking to myself, even if there is an endogeneity problem, how much could it hurt to estimate $\rho$ with OLS rather than set it to one? On the other hand, are there benefits to estimating $\rho$ (with OLS or a more sophisticated procedure) rather than just modeling the change?